# How to setup Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, smartface.io

I have installed SmartFace for the first time and followed the guides but cannot get a software emulator to load (as in the hello world youtube example).

When I click on Start Debug I get:

"Syntax check is completed. No syntax errors.
Checking Android SDK Configuration.
Searching Devices...
Could not detect any connected Android device on your computer!
Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
Deploying is failed."

I do have a Galaxy GT-I1890N plugged in to the USB port, but I cant seem to get that recognised either.

For now I would be happy just to get a software emulator working. 
I have AVD Manager installed which shows there is a Nexus_5_API_21_x86 virtual device on the system, but I cannot get SmartFace App Studio to use it.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Anybody ?  The problem seems to be that the project setting insist on selecting a USB device.  I dont want a physical device. I want to use the software emulator only.  Can anyone advise please.

Comment: Also note I have now put Android Studio on the same machine, and it is able to use an android  software emulator.  WHY CANT SMARTFACE?  Why is it configured to look at the USB port for a device when I dont want to use a physical device.   Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Emulate/Debug on Emulator not on USB, you must select

```
File->Project Details->Debug/Emulator Settings->Virtual Connection
```

in Smartface App Studio. First run your Android Emulator on AVD Manager then Start Emulator from Smartface.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can now deploy my project to an Android virtual device.  However I have to use the Android Studio AVD Manager in order to fire up the emulator.  When I use the one in Android SDK Tools, I just get a Nexus_5_API_22 listed, which has "?" for each of its fields. Start in AVD Manager for this device is disabled. When I try to edit the device the Target list is empty so I can not correct it.  If I try to "Create AVD" I have the same problem, there is nothing in the Target list.  How can I reset AVD Manager in SDK Tools to have/create some devices?

Comment: You must install Android API to create virtual device. Find SDK Manager near to AVD Manager and install e.g. Android 5.1.1. Then you can reopen AVD Manager and select target.

Comment: I have installed this. I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it. I have installed a number of images (as defaulted) from the 5.11 SDK. However when I run All Programs/Android SDK Tools/AVD Manager I get a Nexus API 22 device with ?? in its fields and no Target set. Start button for it is disabled.  When I try to create a new device the Target list is empty and so creation is not possible.  Where are the Targets defined, what would cause them to be absent from my installation?  Am I running AVD manager in the way you are suggesting or is there a different way which leads to a different outcome?